# How to get the keywords & ad clicked from your Adwords campaign?

Tags: google-ads-api

When a user click on my ad on google.com and land on a website page, I'd like to know what keyword they searched for and what ad they clicked and what was the position of the ad.

Is this possible? I've searched on here and on Google but I'm either not searching for the right terminology or it's just impossible?

Thank you,
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very useful article I found after reading your question. Helped me solve some of my doubts as well. Give it a read.

http://certifiedknowledge.org/blog/using-adwords-dynamic-parameters-in-links/